# Many-to-Many relation in sqlalchemy doesnt load while it adds and deletes items

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, many-to-many, self-join

I created a many-to-many self referential relation in SQLAlchemy like this:

```
blacklist_association_table = Table('userblacklist', Base.metadata,
    Column('user_id', Integer, ForeignKey('user.id'), primary_key=True),
    Column('blacklisted_id', Integer, ForeignKey('user.id'), primary_key=True)
)


class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'user'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(250), nullable=True)

    blacklist = relationship("User",
                             secondary=blacklist_association_table,
                             primaryjoin=(id == blacklist_association_table.c.user_id),
                             secondaryjoin=(blacklist_association_table.c.blacklisted_id == id))
```

When I use `append` to add items to `blacklist` field it works and new data is committed to DB

But when I need to access list the `blacklist` field is empty!!
i.e.

```
u = session.query(User).filter(User.id == userid).one_or_none()
print len(u.blacklist)
```

output is `0` while data exists in DB!

What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean to put

```
print len(u.blacklist)
```

Otherwise I think you need more context.

EDIT

can you try:

```
u = session.query(User).filter(User.id == userid).one_or_none()
print len(u.blacklist)
u.blacklist.append(session.query(User).first())
session.commit()
print len(u.blacklist)
u = session.query(User).filter(User.id == userid).one_or_none()
print len(u.blacklist)
```

From what I can tell your code is correct above.
You are saying that you get will get the following output from the above:

```
0
1
0
```

?

Comment: yes, actually I have another field like this and this typo was because of that ; I edited the question; any way both of these fields are empty while data exists in DB

Comment: Yes, Exactly! this is the problem